# Error while using yield in Form:text value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

1) Making CRUD so wanted to use yield in value in Form:text to load the values

```
{!! Form::Text('employeeName_txt',
'@yield('editEmployeeName')',
array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Employee Name')) !!}
```

Getting error

```
FatalErrorException in 2168be22f5078758fb418696bf6815fc3ab642a4.php line 59:
syntax error, unexpected 'editEmployeeName' (T_STRING)
```

Can anyone please help what is wrong in this
& also
2) Which is the best method for CRUD

- Creating Edit page differently & extending it with create page and yield or section the values
- Or in create page only, with the use of if else condition do the coding eg: if route name contains edit then method= put ,delete button show etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
{!! Form::Text('employeeName_txt',"yield('editEmployeeName')", array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Employee Name')) !!}
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in 2168be22f5078758fb418696bf6815fc3ab642a4.php line 75:
syntax error, unexpected 'editTitle' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Error

Comment: Now your main error of this question is gone. It is another error. I advise you use HTML rather than this because you are not conceptually cleared about it and it would waste time if not learnt properly